# Is it possible to produce to a kafka topic when only 1 of the brokers is reachable?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is it possible to produce to a Kafka topic when only 1 of the brokers is reachable from the producer, none of the zookeeper nodes are reachable from the producer, but all of the brokers are healthy and are reachable from each other?

For example, this would be required if I were to produce messages via an SSH tunnel.  If this were for a temporary push I could possibly create the topic with replication factor 1 and have all partitions assigned to the broker in question, and reassign the partitions after the fact, but I'm hoping there is a more flexible setup.

This is all using the java client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Producers don't interact with Zookeeper so it's not an issue.

The only requirement for Producers is to be able to connect to the brokers that are leaders for the partitions they want to use.

If the broker you connect to is the leader for the partitions you want to use, then yes you can produce to it.

Otherwise it's not going to work. Also creating a topic may not help as its partitions could be assigned to any brokers. Also in order to create a topic, a client has to connect to the controller which may not be the broker you can reach.

If you can only connect to 1 "thing", you may want to consider using something like a [REST Proxy](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest). Your "isolated" environment could send REST requests to the proxy which is able to connect to all brokers in the cluster.

Comment: In my case I am only producing to a small and static set of topics known beforehand, so creating the topics in the kafka environment independent of the producer would not have been a problem.  My thought was to use the  --replica-assignment flag of kafka-topics to nail down a topic completely to one broker, and it sounds like this approach would have worked, but I agree, the REST Proxy seems like a better way to go.

Comment: @Mickael Maison  Seems like , all the other brokers are reachable from the broker that is reachable via producer. So if we connect to only 1 broker via producer, this internally will connect to the leader for partitions and will store it on Kafka? This is more of a scenario where 1 broker is in DM zone and other brokers, zookeeper  are connected  with a LAN.

Comment: @Sammy While you only need 1 broker to bootstrap, clients actually connect to all the required brokers directly. Brokers don't internally forward traffic to other brokers, each only handles its own traffic.

Comment: @MickaelMaison Thanks, you are right. But I am assuming (just a floating thought)of a scenario where Partitioner has chosen 3 partitions(hosted on 3 different brokers for a couple of messages . But only one broker was reachable. Now it seems like this type of situation can't happen as the Partitioner will not choose the broker that are not reachable from it. But as the partitions are only hosted on non-reachable broker so it had to wait/timeout/error. 
Thanks again

Comment: It depends on the Partitioner you use. The DefaultPartitioner does not take into account if the producer can connect to all brokers. It just spreads messages across all partitions.